# Planting and farming blinkroot

Tags: terraria

I found some [Blinkroot Seeds](http://wiki.terrariaonline.com/Blinkroot_Seeds) and now want to plant them to get the whole potion brewing going. What do I have to keep in mind when planting those?

I only found [Blinkroot](http://wiki.terrariaonline.com/Blinkroot) underground, so do I also have to plant them underground? Do they have any other requirements?

Comment: Related: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/25288/what-makes-plants-bloom

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Strangely enough, there is nothing to keep in mind.

They will grow anywhere at any level, provided that you plant them in a [Clay Pot](http://wiki.terrariaonline.com/Clay_Pot).

They also grow on plain dirt and mud. However, this is undesirable when making a Blinkroot farm, because fully grown Blinkroots switch on and off at random intervals. They can be harvested all the same, but "inactive" Blinkroots will not drop any seeds. Thus, planting them in Clay Pots is preferable, because they allow for selective harvesting.

Comment: Must you replant the pot after each blinkroot is harvested, or does it self-perpetuate?

Comment: @RavenDreamer They have to be replanted after each harvest. If they're blooming, you're guaranteed at least one seed per drop, though. Blinkroots in particular bloom when they're mature and they feel like it. Other herbs have more specific requirements.