# What makes plants bloom?

Tags: terraria

The latest patch for Terraria added in a bunch of new plants (and their seeds) for use in alchemy.

I'd like to make a sustainable farm for these new plants, but I'm having trouble determining when the plants are in bloom.

What are the conditions underwhich the new plants will "bloom", and produce seeds on harvest? An ideal answer would have a picture of each plant in bloom contrasted with a picture of a plant *not* in bloom.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

- [image: Daybloom] [image: Grown Daybloom] [image: Blooming Daybloom] **Daybloom** blooms when it's day time.
- [image: Moonglow] [image: Grown Moonglow] [image: Blooming Moonglow] **Moonglow** blooms when it's night time.
- [image: Blinkroot] [image: Grown Blinkroot] [image: Blooming Blinkroot] **Blinkroot** blooms (and stops blooming) at random.
- [image: Deathweed] [image: Grown Deathweed] [image: Blooming Deathweed] **Deathweed** blooms only during Blood Moons or a full moon.
- [image: Waterleaf] [image: Grown Waterleaf] [image: Blooming Waterleaf] **Waterleaf** blooms when it's raining.
- [image: Fireblossom] [image: Grown Fireblossom] [image: Blooming Fireblossom] **Fireblossom** blooms during sunset. (3:45 PM - 7:30 PM in-game time)
- [image: Shiverthorn] [image: Grown Shiverthorn] [image: Blooming Shiverthorn] **Shiverthorn** just takes time, and doesn't stop blooming once it does.

---

When blooming, the plants also emit light and/or particle effects.

Comment: That looks perfect. May I ask where you got the images?

Comment: @RavenDreamer There's a tool called [XNB Exporter](http://www.terrariaonline.com/threads/16058/ "XNB Exporter - Extract graphics from Terraria") that can convert the Terraria .xnb sprites to PNG images. Extracting the plants from the sprites was trivial, as their animation consists purely of particle effects.

Comment: Well, neat. I haven't putzed around with Terraria's files, so I don't know what all is or isn't packed away in JARs or what have you.