# Do plants in clay pots have to be offscreen to grow?

Tags: terraria

I'm starting a clay pot farm in Terraria with a modest two pots. One's got daybloom, the other moonglow. I didn't see any information that suggested they had to be offscreen to bloom, so I put my pots in my main base. It's been 5 or 6 days since I planted them, and they're still just little green shoots.

I suspect they have to be offscreen, but I've spent a couple of the past few days mining and expected that would give them enough time to bloom. What the heck did I do wrong?

Comment: Interesting.  I want to say I simply just planted and went on my merry way so when I came back, some had bloomed.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

No, they can grow at any time.

Plants have three states: shoot, growth, and blooming. All plants start as a shoot.

They transition from shoot to growth randomly, and each plant grows at a different rate. The only thing that influences how long this process takes is (pseudo) random chance. Depending on your luck, it could be anywhere from milliseconds to years.

After they've grown, they start blooming when certain conditions are met (which I've detailed in [this answer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/25288/what-makes-plants-bloom#25291)); this too can happen with the player watching.

If you're farming with clay pots, it is best to plant as many shoots of the desired type as possible to mitigate bad growth luck.

Comment: Things like this are why I prefer random rolls for when events will *next* occur, over a simple *if really low number*.

Comment: I've found that Daybloom and Moonglow seem to take the longest to bloom, taking several days, especially in comparison to Blinkroot, which takes mere ingame *hours*.

Comment: Based on this and looking at a few forum posts it seems for many of the plants the only sane strategy is to plant *many* pots to increase odds. Agitating, but can't fight it.

Comment: Should be noted the plants have a chance to bloom only at certain times, like moon glow only blooms when night falls, and daybloom only blooms when the sun rises. They are the static in that state until the shift of time again. This isnt a 100% chance either as mentioned above, they have a Chance to bloom at those times.

Comment: @FallenAngelEyes From anecdotal evidence, I'd say so too, but judging from the code, all alchemy plants seem to grow at the same random pace. Except Blinkroot, which really does grow a lot faster. If an alchemy tile is randomly chosen for a growth update, it has to "win" an additional 1:50 roll to grow; Blinkroot doesn't.

Comment: @James There's a difference between growing and blooming. Growing is a random chance, [blooming](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/25288/what-makes-plants-bloom#25291 "terraria - What makes plants bloom? - Gaming - Stack Exchange") is random only for Blinkroot.

Comment: I just had a daybloom bloom on screen. I think @lunboks is right, but I'm going to edit in something I think it leaves unclear. Seems like blinkroot is crazy fast and all other plants have similar growth rates.

Answer (score 2):

1) Daybloom can blossom anywere aslong as its above ground and in a normal biome (green grass) ...

2) moonglow can grow anywere were their is a jungle biome/ (over 150 or more jungle grass) ..... /which trigers a new biome song/

3) Plants do not need to be offscreen to grow. and like "lunboks" said */The only thing that influences how long this process takes is (pseudo) random chance. Depending on your luck, it could be anywhere from milliseconds to years/*

Comment: Daybloom needs to be above sea level (altitude > 0), not necessarily above ground - last night I was very surprised to see a daybloom blooming on some grass deep in a cave. (I had assumed it needed natural light, but the entire screen was dirt-walled.)